# Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration

Tags: spring, gradle

Получил ошибку "Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration" в репозитории пользователя. Не понимаю, почему она произошла и как ее можно исправить?

Application:

```
package nulltiton.projectprogress;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ProjectProgressApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectProgressApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Репозиторий:

```
package nulltiton.projectprogress.repository;

import nulltiton.projectprogress.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Integer, User> {
    User getById(int id);
}
```

MainController:

```
package nulltiton.projectprogress.controllers;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import nulltiton.projectprogress.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MainController {


    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping({"/", "/index", ""})
    public String showMainPage(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("test", userRepository.getById(1));
        return "main/index";
    }
}
```

User:

```
package nulltiton.projectprogress.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String login;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String fatherName;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
}
```

Comment: Может, сущность `User` не помечена как `@Entity`?

Comment: Вроде все на месте

Comment: Для сущности юзера добавьте ещё аннотацию `@NoArgsConstructor`. Пустой конструктор обязательно должен быть у любой сущности, а аннотация `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, идущая транзитивно от `@Data`, не всегда генерирует именно пустой, даже если поля не `final` и не помечены как `@NotNull`. Не знаю, почему это происходит, но замечал такое. И репозиторий пометьте как `@Repository`. И поле `id` в юзере сделайте `Integer`, то есть, используйте обёртку вместо примитивного типа.

Comment: К большому сожалению, не помогло

Comment: А, точно, ошибка оказалась куда проще: поменяйте местами `Integer` и `User` в репозитории

Answer (score 1):

Поменять местами

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Integer, User> {
        User getById(int id);
    }
```

на

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    }
```

Уже есть метод

```
    Optional<T> findById(ID id);
```

Comment: К сожаленпю, ошибка осталась той же, но большое спасибо за совет

Answer (score 0):

Еще вместо @RequiredArgsConstructor

Поставь

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;